# Simplex method can have the same constraints as Big M method?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

For linear programming we can use simplex method if your problem looks like this:

$$\text {max}: c^T x\\
\text{s.t} \\
Ax \leq b \\
x \geq 0
$$

And if we have a problem that looks like this:

$$\text {max}: c^T x\\
\text{s.t} \\
Ax \leq b_1 \\
Ax \geq b_2 \\
x \geq 0
$$

Then we need to use Big M method. But can this way of optimization be still used by simplex? All I need to do is to write this instead?

From $b_2 \leq Ax \leq b_1$ to
$
\begin{bmatrix}
A \\ 
-A 
\end{bmatrix}x \leq \begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\ 
-b_2
\end{bmatrix} 
$

Right?
Or is this a bad way to write? Better to use Big M instead?

Comment: I don't follow, why not have a single constraint $\begin{bmatrix} A \\ -A \end{bmatrix} x \le \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ -b_2 \end{bmatrix}$?? The Big M method is a bit of a hack.

Comment: @cooperhat Single constraint? How is that possible in this case ?

Comment: I mean I think your approach is fine. Are you talking about using Big M to find a feasible solution?

Comment: @cooperhat I'm talking more about if Big M is better because it is faster. Is it faster? Right now I'm duplicate my constraints in simplex. Do I need to do the same In Big M?

Comment: Well, I have seen Big M used for two different things. One is a hack to deal with binary variables (not here), the other is to combine finding a feasible starting point with the full minimisation. The latter may be faster, but it is not a given.

Comment: @cooperhat Thank you. I'm writing all my algorithms in pure C code. That's the real reason if I need to be worried that my C code of simplex was just a waste if time and if I need Big M to solve a constraint like above. Or if I can do that with simplex as well?

Comment: Big M (as far as I am aware) affects the problem formulation, not the algorithm.